# Inputs and targets have different numbers of samples

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have data in Excel file. It consists of 7 cols with 22 row. Four cols input and 3 outputs and when I want to train them I got always these errors below:

```
Error using network/train (line 340)
Inputs and targets have different numbers of samples.

Error in train_neural_network (line 14)
net = train(net, x, y);
```

What should I do?

My neural network code below:

```
clc; close all; clear all;

filename = 'D:\Raneen.xlsx';
sheet = 1;
xlRange = 'A2:D23';
ylRange = 'E2:G23';
x = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange);
y = xlsread(filename,sheet,ylRange);

net = newff(minmax(x),[20,1],{'logsig','purelin','trainlm'});
net.trainparam.epochs = 8000;
net.trainparam.goal = 1e-25;
net.trainparam.lr = 0.01;
net = train(net, x, y);

y_net = net(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you are getting the problem but try this for splitting X and y, it might fix your problem

x = xlsread(filename)

y=x[:,5:]

x=x[:,1:4]